# How to create shopping cart and calculate total money when using DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Recently i've started to create a pizza ordering chat bot with DialogFlow but don't know how to create a shopping cart with it and also calculate total amount order plus total money user have to pay.
Here's something i've been working on but doesn't work, 'basket' parameters seems to be empty.

here's something to provide you more information about what's happening in my DialogFlow. So i have an intent name " item.confirm.yes " . the script is when a customer ask for pizza, they must fill in 3 values : size, type and quantity in intents

"item.start" - this intent will carry 2 contexts are "item" and "item-confirm" to intents "item.confirm.yes". At this point, if customer confirm their order, "item.confirm.yes" intents will put out context "basket".

Here's some logging about intent "item.confirm.yes"

**index json**

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  let intentMap = new Map();

  function showBasket(agent) {
     if (agent.context.get('basket') != null) {
       const basket = agent.context.get('basket'),
             basketItems = basket.parameters.items,
             itemKeys = Object.keys(basketItems);

       var basketOutput = `So far you've got: `;
       for (let i = 0; i < itemKeys.length; i++) {
         let item = basketItems[itemKeys[i]];
         if ((i < 0) && (i === itemKeys.length - 1)) {
           basketOutput += ` and `;
         }
         else if (i > 0) {
           basketOutput += `, `;
         }
         basketOutput += `${item.amount} ${item.type} in ${item.size}`;
       }
       agent.add(basketOutput);
     }
    else {
      agent.add(`There's nothing in your basket`);
    }
  }

  function confirmItem(agent) {
    const item = agent.context.get('item'),
          amount = item.parameters.amount,
          size = item.parameters.size,
          type = item.parameters.type;

    var basketContext = {'name': 'basket', 'lifespan':50, 'parameters': {}},
        items = {};
    if (agent.context.get('basket')) {
      items = agent.context.get('basket').parameters.item;
    }
    item[request.body.responseId] = {
      "type": type,
      "size": size,
      "amount": amount
    };
    basketContext.parameters.items = items;
    console.log(JSON.stringfy(basketContext));
    agent.context.set(basketContext);
    agent.add(`Confirming ${amount} ${type} pizza in ${size}. Anything else ?`);
  }


  intentMap.set('order.showbasket', showBasket);
  intentMap.set('item.confirm.yes', confirmItem);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**package json:**

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "test": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

and when i tried to pull out the basket
**Diagnostic info**

```
{
  "responseId": "bcad0d74-58ae-4f7a-9e00-532ae296b7e6-dd2bbea9",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "basket",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/7180f8e2-a871-a1d5-694b-44f8395c6c30/contexts/basket",
        "lifespanCount": 1
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/intents/fef12ceb-ba15-4b84-9a5f-406aa648c5c8",
      "displayName": "order.showbasket"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 4988
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 4,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED."
  },
  "alternativeQueryResults": [
    {
      "queryText": "basket",
      "languageCode": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

what happening in itent item.confirm.yes when i ordered one pepperoni pizza large

```
{
  "responseId": "04942abf-da3c-4074-9b5b-2fcaf97c053a-9aa0e9ed",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "yes",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Great, anything else ?",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Great, anything else ?"
          ]
        },
        "platform": "FACEBOOK"
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Great, anything else ?"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/498ae696-5e2e-589e-7402-4fd1b803579f/contexts/basket",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "amount": 1,
          "type": "Pepperoni",
          "size": "large",
          "type.original": "pepperoni",
          "amount.original": "one",
          "size.original": "large"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/498ae696-5e2e-589e-7402-4fd1b803579f/contexts/item",
        "lifespanCount": 4,
        "parameters": {
          "amount": 1,
          "type": "Pepperoni",
          "size": "large",
          "type.original": "pepperoni",
          "amount.original": "one",
          "size.original": "large"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/498ae696-5e2e-589e-7402-4fd1b803579f/contexts/item-confirm",
        "lifespanCount": 4,
        "parameters": {
          "size.original": "large",
          "amount": 1,
          "type": "Pepperoni",
          "size": "large",
          "type.original": "pepperoni",
          "amount.original": "one"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/intents/0723f0a9-9f7e-4c04-a57d-0218c2c3ecf9",
      "displayName": "item.confirm.yes"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 4992
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 4,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED."
  },
  "alternativeQueryResults": [
    {
      "queryText": "yes",
      "outputContexts": [
        {
          "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/498ae696-5e2e-589e-7402-4fd1b803579f/contexts/basket",
          "lifespanCount": 4,
          "parameters": {
            "size.original": "large",
            "amount": 1,
            "type": "Pepperoni",
            "size": "large",
            "type.original": "pepperoni",
            "amount.original": "one"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/498ae696-5e2e-589e-7402-4fd1b803579f/contexts/item",
          "lifespanCount": 4,
          "parameters": {
            "amount": 1,
            "type": "Pepperoni",
            "size": "large",
            "type.original": "pepperoni",
            "amount.original": "one",
            "size.original": "large"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/498ae696-5e2e-589e-7402-4fd1b803579f/contexts/item-confirm",
          "lifespanCount": 4,
          "parameters": {
            "size": "large",
            "type.original": "pepperoni",
            "amount.original": "one",
            "size.original": "large",
            "amount": 1,
            "type": "Pepperoni"
          }
        }
      ],
      "languageCode": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? What errors/difficulties are you having in particular?

Answer (score 1):

While it would be helpful if we could see all of the logging generated, there are a couple of things that could point in the direction of what is going on.

Of particular note is that the `outputContext` is set to

```
"outputContexts": [
  {
    "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/7180f8e2-a871-a1d5-694b-44f8395c6c30/contexts/basket",
    "lifespanCount": 1
  }
],
```

This indicates that, at least when we see this debugging, the `basket` context has a lifespan of 1, and no parameters. This certainly seems different than what you're trying to do in `confirmItem(agent)`, so seeing the logging associated with triggering that Intent may be useful.

It does, however, explain what is happening when you call the `showBasket(agent)` handler. Since there don't appear to be any parameters, your line

```
         basketItems = basket.parameters.items,
```

is causing an error, since `basket.parameters` is undefined. Since it is causing an error, and you don't have any `catch` section, then the entire function errors out without sending a response. Since no response is being sent, Dialogflow eventually times out waiting for it, as indicated by the error

```
"message": "Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED."
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time to help me figure out what's going on in my code. here's something to provide you more information about what's happening in my DialogFlow. So i have an intent name " item.confirm.yes " . the script is when a customer ask for pizza, they must fill in 3 values : size, type and quantity in intents " item.start " - this intent will carry 2 contexts are "item" and "item-confirm" to intents "item.confirm.yes". At this point, if customer confirm their order, "item.confirm.yes" intents will put out context " basket ".Here's some logging about intent "item.confirm.yes"

Comment: `        "name": "projects/pizzadelivery-gyahra/agent/sessions/498ae696-5e2e-589e-7402-4fd1b803579f/contexts/basket",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
          "size.original": "large",
          "amount": 2,
          "type": "Pepperoni",
          "size": "large",
          "type.original": "pepperoni",
          "amount.original": "2"
        }`

Comment: If you have additional information, you should update your original question, and then comment that you've done so. Putting detailed information and code in comments is very difficult to read and not generally as useful.

Comment: hey there ! i did update my question, please check and give me your opinions, very appriciate.